# Android difference in pixel position

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

My MotionEvent and my layout seem to give differing location values and I cannot figure out why. I define an image as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pic"
    android:layout_width="17dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pic" />
```

This places the image at (144, 144) in pixels on the emulator I'm testing with because it has a density of 2.0. The pixel location is confirmed with log.v and the parent of the image is simply the layout.

I have an onTouchListener and in a MotionEvent I check the location of the touch:

```
Log.v("pixelsX", String.valueOf(event.getX()));
Log.v("pixelsY", String.valueOf(event.getY()));
```

When I click well above and to the left of the image I set in the XML I get values of 160 and up, which is clearly wrong. That would correspond to a DP location of 80+ even though the click is well before the image.

If I try and add an image at a click location image.setX(event.getX()) (tried using setX/setY and params) the image gets placed ~40 pixels below and to the right of the click. There is no extra padding or anything to the image, and I've tried using different images and it is consistent between them. The parents of the images are always the layout and the layout is connected to the ontouchlistener:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_mine);
layout.setOnTouchListener(touch);
```

So I cannot figure out why there is this difference in location.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `MotionEvent`, but looks like `getX()`/`getY()` returns the X/Y position relative to the whole screen?

Comment: The layout would be the whole screen, no? Although I believe getRawX() is the absolute position relative to the whole screen, either way getRawX() and getX() return the same value. The layout is the whole screen though isn't it? I believe getX() returning the same as getRawX() would confirm this since the onTouchListener is set to the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem; when I created the activity padding was put into the xml for the RelativeLayout causing the locations for the images to be off by the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Here check this chart I got it off this site, per screen size device can be different, check your numbers compared to this chart

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is     the baseline     density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full    screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Here is a method for dp to pixels for if it ever comes in handy

```
public static int dpToPixels(Context context, float dp) {
final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Tx I already have that. The conversion to and from dp and px is not the problem; it is off by a fixed amount no matter where on the screen the event is. If I click at 130,130 the image will be placed around 160,160 if I click at 0,0 it will be placed around 30,30. Where the touch event looks on screen and where the coordinates are given for the event are consistently off.

Comment: Or better yet, try with different screen size emulators and then use that info to narrow down the problem

Comment: Thanks for the help! That is why I should have put up entire XML code!

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out